# How to navigate all connectors connected to a specific connector in SPPID V10

Tags: c#

I would like to find all the Connectors that are connected to a specific Connector based on ConnectItem2SymbolObject in SPPID V10 using C# .net as the programming tool.

I would like to find all the Connectors that are connected to a specific Connector based on ConnectItem2SymbolObject in SPPID V10 using C# .net as the programming tool..